# Вложенный запрос с конкатенацией в update и select

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, update

Добрый день не могли бы помочь с вложенным запросом с конкатенацией в `select` и `update`. В общем, есть необходимость пробежать по таблице, найти имена с вхождением определенного текста и вставить в них разрыв знаком. Среда ругается что возвращается больше одного значения, как организовать это?
Первоначально запрос выглядел так:

```
UPDATE dbo.UserLogin 
SET LoginName = (
                SELECT 
                    (
                        (
                            SELECT SUBSTRING(LoginName,1,7) 
                            FROM dbo.UserLogin 
                            WHERE LoginName LIKE '%SRVMAIN_\%'
                        )
                    + '!' 
                    + (
                        SELECT SUBSTRING(LoginName,8,LEN(LoginName)) 
                        FROM dbo.UserLogin 
                        WHERE LoginName LIKE '%SRVMAIN_\%'
                        )
                    )
                ) 
WHERE LoginName LIKE '%SRVMAIN_\%'
```

В последствии покопавши на форуме нашел подобную конструкцию:

```
UPDATE t1 
SET t1.LoginName = t2.LoginName
FROM dbo.UserLogin as t1 
JOIN dbo.UserLogin as t2 on t1.ID_User=t2.ID_User 
    and t2.LoginName in (
                        select 
                            (
                                (
                                    SELECT SUBSTRING(LoginName,1,7) 
                                    FROM dbo.UserLogin 
                                    WHERE LoginName LIKE '%SRVMAIN_\%'
                                )
                            + '!' 
                            + (
                                SELECT SUBSTRING(LoginName,8,LEN(LoginName)) 
                                FROM dbo.UserLogin 
                                WHERE LoginName LIKE '%SRVMAIN_\%'
                                )
                            )
                        ) 
WHERE t1.LoginName LIKE '%SRVMAIN_\%'
```

И как написать `select` чтобы посмотреть, что именно я меняю до запуска `update`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update dbo.UserLogin 
set LoginName = SUBSTRING(LoginName, 1, 7) 
              + '!' 
              + SUBSTRING(LoginName, 8, LEN(LoginName))
where LoginName like '%SRVMAIN_\%'
```

А ещё лучше

```
update dbo.UserLogin 
set LoginName = STUFF(LoginName, 8, 0, '!')
where LoginName like '%SRVMAIN_\%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, так:

```
select t1.LoginName name1, t2.LoginName name2
  from dbo.UserLogin as t1 
  join dbo.UserLogin as t2 on t1.ID_User=t2.ID_User and t2.LoginName in (select ((select SUBSTRING(LoginName,1,7) from dbo.UserLogin where LoginName like '%SRVMAIN_\%')
   + '!' + (select  SUBSTRING(LoginName,8,LEN(LoginName)) from dbo.UserLogin where LoginName like '%SRVMAIN_\%'))) where t1.LoginName like '%SRVMAIN_\%'
```